# Place to define EXTRAS in Android

Tags: java, android

Sometimes we need to pass information between Activities/Fragments through intents, attaching Extras in the form of key-values. We define those keys in specific parts of our code, usually the forwarding Activity/Fragment.

I was wondering how good/bad would it be to define those keys inside an interface that we later implemented in the necessary classes. Something like this:

```
public interface {

public static final String EXTRA_STRING_1 = "com.myownapp.android.string_1";
public static final String EXTRA_STRING_2 = "com.myownapp.android.string_2";
...

}
```

I know defining variables inside an interface is considered to be a 'controversial' topic. I just wanted to know your thoughs around it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56949/where-to-define-constants-bundle-keys-used-between-2-activities

Comment: I don't think its a good idea to use it inside an interface or even in an activity or fragment, i would rather create a Class file separately which holds all the static final values which are used in the app Which helps you to organize your code.

Comment: @antonio : The code in the question and answer in the link you posted are both anti-patterns for designing Android apps. The safest and most versatile and reusable way to do things is with a POJO as suggested by Lochana Ragupathy in the comment above.

Comment: @Squonk Thanks a lot for pointing it out, I've been doing it this way thinking it was OK... I will do a bit of research

Comment: Make the POJO holding the constants `final` and let it have a `private` constructor. Use `import static` for importing the constants into each class. Or just reference them using the whole qualified class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve this problem by creating a seperate class `Constants`. It contains all constant variables that are used in several classes. Example:

```java
public class Constants {
    public static final String EXTRA_STRING_1 = "com.myownapp.android.string_1";
    public static final String EXTRA_STRING_2 = "com.myownapp.android.string_2";
    //even more constants...

    //private constructor, class can't be instantiated
    private Constants() {}
}
```

You can use it like this in any other class:

```
intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_STRING_1, "text");
```